# Trying to display an ipcam on my website but a popup isn't being displayed and preventing the video feed

Tags: javascript, php, html

Creates a popup that I cant see on my website and just says connection unavailable.

Typing in the address of the camera:

```
http://<IP-ADDRESS>:<PORT>/video.cgi?user=<USER>&password=<PASSWORD>
```

Still pops up a input box to type in the credentials so passing the uname and pw doesn't work.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="randomClass">
        <img src="user@<IP-ADDRESS>:<PORT>/video.cgi" alt="Connection to camera lost" width="400" height="220">
    </div>
</div>
```

Hoping to find a way to connect to the camera without it requiring access to the pop up.

UPDATE: Decided to just disable UAC. This allows anyone on the network to view the camera but I'll just close it up a little more.

Comment: Can you please post the HTML code you get when you type the address of the camera  ? You can see the code from your browser with right-click > view source menu (name may vary slightly depending on your browser). This code should provide some hint for passing the username and pwd properly

Comment: It actually pops up a locked username and password box. F12, right click, dev options etc. are all disabled to view input on popup. That's what pushed my decision to just disable UAC on the camera and lock it up a different way. Thanks though!